# What is different Callback vs new AsyncCallback(Callback)?

Tags: c#, network-programming, asyncsocket

For AsyncSocket

```
// accept
...
listener.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
// listener.BeginAccept( AcceptCallback, listener);
...

public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
...
}

// recieve
...
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), asyncSocket);
// socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, length, 0, ReadCallback, asyncSocket);
...

public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
...
}
```

We can use just Callback instead new AsyncCallback(Callback)

What is different just Callback vs new AsyncCallback(Callback)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same.  The "new" keyword was needed in older versions of the compiler.  The newer version of the compiler can infer the delegate.  The same code is generated either way.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is what I want.

Comment: @user2523112 - in addition, most of the Visual Studio "generated" code still uses the "new" keyword delegate syntax.  So you still see that in .Designer.cs files and the like.

Answer (score 2):

> What is different just Callback vs new AsyncCallback(Callback)?

Its called [*Delegate Inference*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163970.aspx). The former lets the compiler infer the delegate type, the latter explicitly states it.